# belongs_to with :class_name option fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have no idea what went wrong but I can't get belongs_to work with :class_name option. Could somebody enlighten me. Thanks a lot!

Here is a snip from my code.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.text :name
        end
    end

    def self.down
        drop_table :users
    end
end

#####################################################

class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :books do |t|
            t.text :title
            t.integer :author_id, :null => false
        end
    end

    def self.down
        drop_table :books
    end
end

#####################################################

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many: books
end

#####################################################

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User', :validate => true
end

#####################################################

class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def create
        user = User.new({:name => 'John Woo'})
        user.save
        @failed_book = Book.new({:title => 'Failed!', :author => @user})
        @failed_book.save # missing author_id
        @success_book = Book.new({:title => 'Nice day', :author_id => @user.id})
        @success_book.save # no error!
    end
end
```

environment:

ruby 1.9.1-p387
Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 66):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :foreign_key => 'author_id'
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'author_id', :validate => true
end
```

The best thing to do is to change your migration and change `author_id` to `user_id`. Then you can remove the `:foreign_key` option.

Comment: I care about having good foreign keys. I wouldn't apply the suggestion about renaming the column, as it's clearer what's going on when the columns have the right name.

Comment: Either way works. Whatever makes sense for you and your team is the right thing to do. :)

Comment: And to think that class_name: 'User' would have sufficed

Answer (score 8):

It should be

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'author_id'
```

if your foreign key is author id. Since you actually have User class, your Book must belong_to :user.

Answer (score 3):

I do in this way:

Migration -

```
class AddAuthorToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :author, index: true
    add_foreign_key :posts, :users, column: :author_id
  end
end
```

class Post

```
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
```

Answer (score 3):

migration

```
t.belongs_to :author, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

working on rails 5