# Belongs_to alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get the username of comment author like this

```
comment.commenter
```

models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :commenter
 belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

 has_many :comments, as: :commenter
end
```

When i try to create Comment directly to db using this line of code:

```
Comment.create(commentable_type: 'Pokemon', commentable_id: 1, content: 'great', commenter: 1)
```

It throws this error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Comment::Commenter
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:158:in `compute_type'
```

I've read somewhere as: is used only for polymorphic assocciations so that might be the case of my error but couldn't figure out how to get around this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `as:` is what you are looking for. I think your issue is similar to the issue in [belongs_to with :class_name option fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684843/belongs-to-with-class-name-option-fails)

Try

```
# user.rb
has_many :comments, foreign_key: "commenter_id"

# comment.rb
belongs_to :commenter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "commenter_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain a bit before going to the solution, if you write this code:

```
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
```

It implicitly means:

```
belongs_to :commentable, foreign_key: 'commentable_id', foreign_type: 'commentable_type', polymorphic: true
```

And

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
```

It specifies the syntax of polymorphic, that also means the `foreign_key` is `commentable_id` and `foreign_type` is `commentable_type` so if you want to change `commentable` to commenter, it is possible, you can do like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commenter, foreign_key: 'commentable_id', foreign_type: 'commentable_type', polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: commentable
end
```

That 's it!

For detail, please go through [has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) and [belongs_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) documentation

Comment: i wouldn't want to change commentable to commenter since i need it for other purposes